# YCM: how to toggle information box when cursor is over e.g. a function?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

Using the YouCompleteMe plugin, I'd like to be able to move my cursor over e.g. a function in all supported languages (e.g. JS), and use some keybinding to toggle the information dialog on/off. (At the moment, I have to wait a few seconds for the box to show; I'd prefer to control it explicitly).

Is this possible?

Comment: It could be that setting `updatetime` smaller would help; not manual, though

Answer (score 2):

Add to your config:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>h <plug>(YCMHover)
```

I prefer `K` for that, but only for buffers/filetypes, where it makes sense:

```
let s:lsp_ft_maps = 'gdscript,go,python'

augroup ycm_settings | au!
    exe printf('au FileType %s call Ycm_mappings()', s:lsp_ft_maps)
augroup end

func! Ycm_mappings() abort
    nmap <silent><buffer> K <plug>(YCMHover)
    nnoremap <silent><buffer> gd :YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>
endfunc
```

**UPD**

This snippet creates an autocommand for filetypes listed in `s:lsp_ft_maps` that runs `Ycm_mappings()` function, that in turn creates buffer local mappings.

Buffer local mappings as name suggests are only available for a given buffer thus if you switch to another buffer where YCM doesn't have LSP functionality, original mappings would be in effect.

For example, `K` is used by vim to show a man page of a keyword under cursor, and for `vim` filetype (say your .vimrc), the same `K` is used to show vim help. With the snippet, it is preserved for non-lsp related buffers and shows YCM hover for buffers listed in `s:lsp_ft_maps` variable.

The same is with `gd` mapping -- it has original built-in functionality which this snippet overrides for some of filetypes.

Comment: Thanks. The first line seems to do what I want. I don't understand the rest of what you've written though. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Magnus see update. But if the first line works for you, don't bother :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
" turn off hover info
let g:ycm_auto_hover = ''

" toggle hover info with F3
map <F3> <plug>(YCMHover)
```